# Displaying null IEnumerable with EditorTemplate

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, mvc-editor-templates

I have a complex object which has a IEnumerable property and that I want to display in my view.

For that purpose I've created an EditorTemplate for that list.

So, in my view I have the following code:

```
<div id="tabMed" class="tab-pane">
    <fieldset>   
        <div>
            @Html.EditorFor(m => m.MyList)
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

m.List is an IEnumerable type and the Editor template has inside some fields for displaying the object.

This works fine when the list has 1 or more objects; it will display and repeat the template for every object in that list.

Now the problem:

Let's supose that I want to edit the object that contains that list and the IEnumerable property is null. The Editor template won't appear at all, leaving no possibility to create the first object in that list.

Is there any approach to show an empty template if the list is null without having to something like this?:

```
<div id="tabMed" class="tab-pane">
    <fieldset>   
        <div>
            @if (Model.MyList.Count() > 0)
            {
                @Html.EditorFor(m => m.MyList)
            }
            else
            {
                // empty object form template here...
            }
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

Edit: The EditorTemplate look like this:

```
@model Jazz.Models.MyList.MyObject

<div class="control-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => Model.Name, new { @class="control-label"})
    <div class="controls">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name, new { @class="collection-item", autocomplete = "off", maxlength = 64 })
    </div>
</div>
```

The MyList is the list that I want to display

The MyObject class is declared inside MyList

So, the model would be like this:

```
public class MyList
{
    public MyList()
    {
        this.list = new List<MyObject>();
    }

    public int id{ get; set; }

    public List<MyObject> list{ get; set; }

    public class MyObject
    {
        public MyObject(){}

        public string Name{ get; set; }

    }
}
```

I've put the example in a generic way so it's simplier to show the problem.

Comment: Can't you just initialize an empty list in your model's constructor?

Comment: Even if the list exists but with no objects, it won't display the template. The only way I see is to add an empty object to that list. But I don't know if this is a very elegant solution.

Comment: What does your EditorTemplate look like?

Comment: Hi Rowan, I've updated the post

Comment: Instead of typing the template to the individual object, type it to the `MyList` class and then enumerate over the list inside the template?

Comment: Not sure if that will be suitable for my scenario because actually MyList has more than one list within and of different types. For instance: it has a List<MyObjectA> and List<MyObjectB>. And MyObjectA has also other lists inside, and so on... It a very complex object.

Comment: Nonetheless I will try your approach and tell you later :)